# WebApi, OData and ConventionErrors

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am struggling with the OData WebApi way to configure routing - mostly by not being able to get any sensible debugging information.

The API in question is part of a server service (as in: windows service) and as such OWIN based.

I have for example the following function:

```
function = builder.Function("MktSessions").ReturnsCollection<MktSession>();
function.Parameter<string>("Symbol");
function.Parameter<DateTimeOffset>("Begin");
function.Parameter<DateTimeOffset>("End");
```

and the controller has the following signature function:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("MktSessions(Symbol={symbol},Begin={begin},End={end}")]
public IEnumerable<Reflexo.Api.MktSession> MktSessions (string symbol, DateTime begin, DateTime end) {
```

SOMETHING is wrong here. As long as the ODataRouter attbribute is presend, any call to $metadata resunlts in:

> An error has occurred. 
>   The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that
>   HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's
>   startup code after all other initialization code. 
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>    at
>   System.Web.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.get_AttributeMappings()
>   at
>   System.Web.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.SelectController(ODataPath
>   odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request) at
>   System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.SelectControllerName(ODataPath
>   path, HttpRequestMessage request) at
>   System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, IHttpRoute route, String parameterName, IDictionary`2 values,
>   HttpRouteDirection routeDirection) at
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraint(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Object constraint, String parameterName,
>   HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection) at
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraints(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection
>   routeDirection) at
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot,
>   HttpRequestMessage request) at
>   System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__0.MoveNext()

which is as useless as it gets as an error message. I never have a chance to see  original exception and this one jsut tells me the config is not there - which has no direct resemblence of the original error.

If I remove the ODataRoute attribute it works - but I can obviously not call the function.

Is there any way I am overlooking to actually get a meaningfull error message from this? Obviously the ODataRoute is somewhere in error (anyone knows where?) and a sensible "Parameter name blablbla does not match" text somewhere would be really helpfull.

Comment: You've declared the function parameters as `DateTimeOffset`, but the method signature uses `DateTime`. Not saying that's the source of the problem, but you should still correct it.

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce the problem from the info in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself.

Now, on the side question there is a missing ")" at the end of the template.

More important, though.

When I add a call to HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() to the end of the Owin configuration then I get the exception thrown there. This exception - while not having an inner exception - contains a meaningfull  message that is lost in the web page output. This allows much better debugging.

Comment: What was the "meaningfull message"?  I'm getting the exact same error setting up an odata method next to an existing MVC api set in IIS, but I'm not getting any exception thrown when I call EnsureInitialized() in App_Start.  Nor is VS 2015 breaking on System.InvalidOperationException even though I have it checked on the Exception Settings

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code your paste,
1. In the ODataRoute, you miss ")" after "{end}"
2. You should have define MktSessions as entity set, so your unbound function route can not be same as an entity set, you can change it to something else like RetrieveMktSessions as EntitySet query is enable by get method in controller but not a unbound function.

Let us know if you have any more issues.